# Email column required in grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using telerik mvc grid and bound my columns throuugh Data Table, I having a column "Email", where I need to format this column in such a way, so that user can do the mail by clicking on email..

I'm using a "MailTo" extension to format the column, but it's not work for me...

Any idea to do achieve the same by this/other way

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.Data.DataTable>
@BHN.PayGo.ASP.Web.Utilities.Extensions              

@if (Model != null)
{

@(Html.Telerik().Grid<System.Data.DataRow>(Model.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>()).Name("grdHierarchy")
  .Columns(columns =>
     {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
           {
             if (column.ColumnName == "Email")
                    {
                        columns.Bound(column.DataType, column.ColumnName).Title("Email").Format(Html.Mailto("{0}", "{0}")).Encoded(false);
                    }
                }
      })

     .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_HierarchyBinding", "Reports"))
     .Pageable(settings => settings.Total((int)ViewData["TOTAL_ACCOUNTHIERARCHY_DATA"]))
     .EnableCustomBinding(true)
     .Sortable(settings => settings.Enabled(false))
     .Scrollable(settings => settings.Enabled(true).Height("auto"))
)

}
uuired
```

Comment: did you tried post this into Telerik Forum? They have Support Staff there to help you with code, and all users there use Telerik components! http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Ajax Databinding you will need to use client templates (rather than the server side templates you have used): see http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesclientside